# Windows Server 2016TP5 Sysprep setupdigetclassdevs failed with error 0

Tags: packer, windows-server-2016, sysprep

I do Windows Server 2016TP5 build with Packer.
ISO is downloaded from MSDN, and hash is fine.
Packer on my machine is working fine with Linux and Windows Server 2012R2.
Autounattend and scripts are almost the same as for 2012R2, all scripts can run successfully on test VM with WS2015TP5.

The problem is that sysprep fails with error
*setupdigetclassdevs failed with error 0*

I've tried:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUser | Remove-AppxPackage
Stop-Service -Name "tiledatamodelsvc"
Set-Service -Name "tiledatamodelsvc" -StartupType Disabled
Set-ItemProperty -Path "registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\SysprepStatus" -Name "GeneralizationState" -Value 7
```

... but nothing helped.
Any ideas about how it can be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with shutdown_command A:/sysprep.bat instead of plaintext command
The same solution works for 2012r2 as well.